# Sending SIGINT from keyboard to piped commands in bash

Tags: linux, bash, signals

If in bash I run `a | b | c | d` on the command line and then press <kbd>^C</kbd>, which process gets the signal?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In short, they all do.

When setting up a pipeline, the shell creates a *[process group](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=366888&seqNum=8)*. <kbd>^C</kbd> is interpreted by the kernel's line discipline as the user's request to interrupt the process group currently running in the foreground. Sending a signal such as `SIGINT` to a process group automatically delivers the signal to all processes in the group.

Answer (score 8):

I like experimentation better:

```
#!/bin/bash
# FILE /tmp/bla.sh
# trap ctrl-c and call ctrl_c()
trap ctrl_c INT

MY_ID=$1 # Identifier for messages

function ctrl_c() {
    echo >&2 "GOODBYE $MY_ID"
    exit
}

# This will continue until interrupted, e.g. if the input/output get closed
cat
# If we somehow got to the end
echo >&2 "grace $MY_ID"
```

Chaining them, running and breaking them

```
nitz@mars:~$ /tmp/bla.sh 1 | /tmp/bla.sh 2
^CGOODBYE 2
GOODBYE 1
0
```

As you can see, both executions got the interrupt signal, meaning they all get killed. Furthermore, the order in which they output that they were killed is random, e.g.:

```
nitz@mars:~$ /tmp/bla.sh 1 | /tmp/bla.sh 2 | /tmp/bla.sh 3 | /tmp/bla.sh 4
^CGOODBYE 2
GOODBYE 4
GOODBYE 1
GOODBYE 3
```

Comment: "Furthermore, the order in which they output that they were killed is random" thanks a ton! I think this is really important.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the excellent (I also love experimentation) answer by @Nitz, if you do *not* want all the processes to get the signal, you can use bash process substitution (thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9888720/1410035)).

Here's an example that shows the `1` process does get the signal, but the `2` and `3` processes do not.

```
$ /tmp/bla.sh 1 > >(/tmp/bla.sh 2 | /tmp/bla.sh 3)
^CGOODBYE 1
grace 2
grace 3
```

You can also redirect stderr and it still works.

My use case was trying to filter output from a command that is the entrypoint for a docker container, but I don't want to mess with signal handling of the main process.

Edit: there seem to be some buffering issues for some combinations of commands, but I don't understand why. So, this may not suit your use case.

```
# no buffering issues here
(echo 1; sleep 1; echo 2; sleep 2; echo 3) > >(cat)
(echo 1; sleep 1; echo 2; sleep 2; echo 3) > >(cat | cat | cat)
(echo 1; sleep 1; echo 2; sleep 2; echo 3) > >(cat | grep -v blah)
# no output until original command finishes for this *shrugs*
(echo 1; sleep 1; echo 2; sleep 2; echo 3) > >(grep -v blah | cat)
```